# Docpad: Regeneration fails with no apparent reason

Tags: node.js, docpad

When I run `docpad run`, there are times after I write changes to disk, and the process tries to regenerate it fails to do so. It's not a matter of it taking a long time, it just fails to regenerate, even on subsequent writes. I have to interrupt the process (i.e. ctrl+d in the console) and restart the process all over again.

My env:

- Linux Mint Debian 64-bit
- node@0.8.17
- npm@1.2.2
- docpad@6.21.7
- docpad-plugins:

  - jade@2.2.0
  - livereload@2.2.0
  - robotskirt@2.0.1
  - stylus@2.2.0

Has anyone encountered this behavior before?

Comment: Very strange. Can you reproduce this issue with any of the standard skeletons? And is your project available on github so we can take a look? Also, do you have any other machines you can try it on? Trying process of elimination here.

Comment: Didn't encounter it with a new HTML5 boilerplate site. The project is [here](https://github.com/imaginationac/imaginationac.github.com/tree/develop); checkout the develop branch.

Comment: It happens to me some times, that after fast changes of source files I get Page Not Found. Is this what you get too @DorianPatterson ?

Comment: Seems to occur if I write a change before the previous regeneration is done.

Answer (score 1):

As a precaution try running `ulimit -n 4096` in your console.

This has solved a number of miscellaneous failures in my docpad instance.